# jquery selectors - getElementById vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-selectors

Are these two definitions of map functionally equivalent?

```
    var target = $('#mapcontainer')[0];
    console.log(target);                                // = <div id="mapcontainer" height="311px" width="1708px">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(target , options);
```

and

```
    console.log(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"));       // also equals = <div id="mapcontainer" style="height: 311px; width: 1708px;">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);
```

Second one gives me map, first one dies gracefully.  Maybe map API is picky about format received?

follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833431/javscript-to-jquery-queryselector-and

Comment: They are equal in that the returned result will be the same.

Comment: _"Maybe map API is picky about format received?"_ - Your two examples both pass the same "format". That is, they both pass a reference to a DOM element, _assuming the element exists_ - if the element does not exist the first method passes `undefined` but the second passes `null`. _"first one dies gracefully"_ - What does that mean? No errors in the JS console?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just the wrapper of javascript. If you are more concerned about the performance, you should go with getElementByID. But, using jQuery will provide the extra methods to deal with element.
`$(document.getElementById('mapcontainer')).jqueryCall();`
This will give jquery methods and at the same time performance.
Hope this helps!d

Comment: not about performance. just trying some examples to help really understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: well, .jQueryCall() is your any jquery method that is associated to that element. underhood everybody is using basic javascript methods.